# What is the correct way to write sodium tetraphenylborate formula?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_tetraphenylborate), it is written in two different ways.

(C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>5</sub>)<sub>4</sub>BNa and NaB(C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>5)4</sub>

Is there not a unique criterion? Or is it chemistry-brach-dependant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than two, in that article: SMILES shows bonding. `[B-](C1=CC=CC=C1)(C2=CC=CC=C2)(C3=CC=CC=C3)C4=CC=CC=C4.[Na+]`.

A brief online survey shows [[Alfa](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/A10909.14), [Chemical Book](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB5393075.htm), [Fisher](https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/sodium-tetraphenylboron-0-02m-ricca-chemical/785532), [Sigma](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/substance/sodiumtetraphenylborate34222143668) and [NIH](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Sodium-tetraphenylborate) prefer metal-last, though most also show the SMILES string.

A few outliers, such as [Enmore](http://ennoreindiachemicals.com/blog/sodium-tetraphenylborate-supplier-distributor-manufacturer-chennai-taminadu-india), [Grainger](https://www.grainger.com/product/SPECTRUM-Sodium-Tetraphenylborate-39G977) and [WebQC](https://www.webqc.org/molecular-weight-of-NaB%28C6H5%294.html), still use the metal-first layout.

The answer might be, *"The preferred format is the one chosen by the instructor or administrator."*